# How can I run Lambda function using an Ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a code with an S3 PUT trigger using Lambda but the code involves the pandas library and Lambda is not supporting that.
Even after deploying a Deployment package with pandas library, its not working.
So i am thinking of creating a Linux instance on EC2 and installing python with pandas in that and using the same to run my code via Lambda.

Is there any method by which this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the AWS SAM CLI. With that you can even run your Lambda functions locally.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Yes I can run, but the problem here is to run the code having pandas library. For that only i want an alternative.

Comment: install pandas into your package folder and upload it together.

Comment: or you can use lambda layer, see [this](https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e)

Comment: >  pandas library and Lambda is not supporting that This is not true. https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e